# Enable Volunteer Opportunity Listing with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, civivolunteer

I am using CiviVolunteer with wordpress and I am trying to enable the volunteer Opportunity Listing. I tried the following link the http://address-to-your-site/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities link with my domain and I am not able to see it. I have angular profiles enabled, and I granted access to AJAX API and CiviVolunteer: register to volunteer to anonymous users, but I am still not able to see this list publicly. Is there something else wordpress users need to do to view the volunteer opportunity listing?

Answer (score 3):

If your wordpress install will not show volunteer opportunities, this is what worked for me:

/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

instead of:
/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities

Answer (score 0):

It has comes to my attention that the http://address-to-your-site/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities  URL is for CiviVolunteer setup on Drupal, which is the developer's preferred platform.  The URL Christophe gave you is the correct URL for Wordpress.